# Error reading excel cell with line break into Dataset

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, oledb

I have a peculiar issue where I am trying to read values from excel into a dataset in c#.

Some of my excel cell contains a line break like this. (Press Alt+ Enter in a cell to include line break within a cell)

[image: Press Alt+ Enter in a cell to include line break within a cell]

While reading this excel in my program through Fill Command. This line break is read as "_".

[image]

How do i address this scenario? Either I want to clean up all the escape sequence before importing from excel.

Comment: you mean, because the problem only happens in one column?

Comment: No. "\n" - line break gives me _. I am wondering, what do other escape sequence might give me.

Comment: Maybe you have to replace `\n || \n\r` with `Environment.NewLine` ?

Comment: I dont want an new line. I want to remove the \n from excel that is being transformed as " _ " after reading through oledb.